# Send SMS like this in body :"{FirstName}, Happy New Year" in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, sms

HI friends here is my question

Im working on groupsms im having a problem while sending sms to bulk,

im sending my body msg like this:"{FirstName}, Happy New Year".i need to enter first name of every contact to that respectable contact.when im sending it makes me press every time to every contact.suppose 5 persons means 5 times i need to click on send,is their any possibility to overcome this like by pressing 1 time and send to every bdy

for your reference im attacthing a image check this out,i will be thankfull for you if help me out. :)

[image]

Comment: i am not sure but i don't think that you can change the Fist-name. but you can send same message to many recipients

Comment: @NitinGohel would mind sharing how ?

Comment: @KunalBalani i am talking about that you can't change Message Body. with same message you can send bulk message to many user with same message body

Comment: @NitinGohel I understand that , would you mind sharing any code or link please how to send message to multiple users without modifying body

Comment: @CodeWorrior are you asking to me or saying to kunal?

Comment: @NitinGohel dnt mind :) i just confused

Answer (score 1):

As i told that you can't modify Message Body but you can send Bulk SMS with same message Body like bellow way:-

```
 MFMessageComposeViewController *myMessageComposeViewController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

 if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) {

        myMessageComposeViewController.body = @"Happy Birthday to you";
        myMessageComposeViewController.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"12345678", @"87654321", nil];
        myMessageComposeViewController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        myMessageComposeViewController.delegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:myMessageComposeViewController animated:YES];

        }
```

and also you can handle the status of message

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a default behavior of email & message API. If there is a way to send SMS to every person in contact list without user's intervention then anyone could easily spam.

Comment: ,firstly thanks for your time,that means you are conforming that we cant edit the body mesgs dynamically .right :)

Comment: @CodeWorrior how did you arrive to this conclusion from my answer.

Comment: yes i know that ios have some strict rules,we cant go denying them.so you are saying is that possible to send dynamic msg generated can send to group contacts,sorry if im wrong ,can you explain me how to go on with this puzle